# Is Elmo equivalent to Fasttext+Bi-directional GRU?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, word-embeddings, multilabel, gru

From what I have read, Elmo uses bi-directional LSTM layers to give contextual embeddings for words in a sentence. So if I use a bi-directional LSTM/GRU layer over Fasttext representations of words, will it be the same? If not why? (I know that Fasttext works at the sub-word level while Elmo works at character level)

Also, does it make sense to use a bi-directional LSTM/GRU layer over the representations produced by Elmo?

The task that I am working on is extreme multi-label classification of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I use a bi-directional LSTM/GRU layer over Fasttext
>   representations of words, will it be the same?

Sep. 27, 2018 the authors published a follow on work to ELMo, "[Dissecting Contextual Word Embeddings: Architecture and Representation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08949.pdf)". They test whether a bidirectional language model (biLM) can be replicated using Transformers, CNNs, and deeper LSTMs.

They find LSTMs are still the best but a Transformer and CNN representation is much faster and uses much fewer parameters while not being much different result wise. Here are some results from the paper:
[image]

They suggest that the general biLM approach seems to work regardless of architecture:

> We have shown that deep biLMs learn a rich hierarchy of contextual information, both at the word
>   and span level, and that this is captured in three
>   disparate types of network architectures.

Your specific representation of FastText+Bi-Directional GRU wasn't tried in the paper but this would suggest it's plausible. I would guess it will probably achieve some sort of result, 50%-90% as good as ELMo but much faster.

> Also, does it make sense to use a bi-directional LSTM/GRU layer over the
>   representations produced by Elmo?

Yes, you can use any type of architecture over the embedding produced by ELMo. Make sure you explore weighing the layers of ELMo and/or taking separate layers and concatenating them, as per the original ELMo paper.

Answer (score 0):

The new idea in the ELMo paper is add to a deep recurrent net a time-distributed linear layer which combines the word representations learnt at each layer. They show that this makes transfer learning more effective. The deep net can be trained unsupervised on a big corpus. Then it can be reused with a small supervised corpus by training the linear layer and a recurrent output layer, while freezing the weights of the deep recurrent net.